# How can I bind the configuration from a JSON file to an instance of in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, configuration

I want to bind the configuration from a JSON file to an instance of **`HttpApiClientOptions`**. However, I encountered some issues when binding the **`Body`** property. After defining it as **`Dictionary<string, object>?`**, the **`Body`** property correctly contains the **`model`** and **`temperature`** key-value pairs, but the value of **`messages`** is empty, and I'm unable to retrieve **`{"role":"user", "content":"hello!"}`** from it.

C# Code:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(configFilePath, false, false)
    .Build();
//...
config.GetSection("apiClientOptions").GetSection(apiClientName).Bind(apiClientOptions);
```

HttpApiClientOptions Class:

```
public class HttpApiClientOptions : BaseApiClientOptions
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string>? Headers { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string>? Params { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object>? Body { get; set; }
}
```

JSON Configuration:

```json
{
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer sk-"
    },
    "params": {},
    "body": {"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role":"user", "content":"hello!"}], "temperature": 0.7}
}
```

I attempted to define **`Body`** as **`JObject`** or **`JsonElement`**, but this approach also failed to retrieve values from the first level of nesting.

The reason I did not map the entire **`Body`** node to a specific type is that the contents and nesting depth under the **`Body`** node are uncertain. Is there any way to make the program read all the information inside the **`body`** node from the JSON file during configuration?

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate, but did you read [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207731/3094533)?

Comment: You should understand one thing, configuration is not JSON, it is collection of key-value pairs, JSON files are not a single source of config. So `Dictionary<string, object>` does not make much sense to binder.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The question only discussed the scenario where the JSON has only one level of nesting. What I want to achieve is to read the content of a node containing multiple layers of nesting into a property.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand one thing, configuration is not JSON, it is collection of key-value pairs, JSON files are not a single source of config. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration):

> Configuration in .NET is performed using one or more configuration providers. Configuration providers read configuration data from key-value pairs using various configuration sources:

> - Settings files, such as appsettings.json
> - Environment variables
> - Command-line arguments
> - ...

So `Dictionary<string, object>` does not make much sense to binder. One option - provide actual types for all levels:

```cs
public class HttpApiClientOptions 
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Headers { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Params { get; set; }
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; } // or List<Dictionary<string,string>>
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Another way would be to exclude `Body` from the model and dynamically read config via `GetChildren` from some point and process results:

```cs
public class HttpApiClientOptions 
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Headers { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Params { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
var body = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Body");
foreach (var section in body.GetChildren())
{
    // recursively process section
}
```

Comment: The content under the `Body` node is uncertain, so I haven't provided an actual type for it. I tried defining 'Body' as other types, but still, I couldn't read the entire content of the 'Body' node into a specific property. The value of `messages` is always missing.

Comment: @TonWin there is not much what can be done. You need to provide some valid structure for reasons explicitly stated in answer. Also what is the point of configuration if it essentially unstructured? How do you want to consume it?

Comment: I want to fill the content of the `body` into the HTTP request's request body, and users can customize the structure of this HTTP request's body to adapt to different APIs of large language models. I will provide some placeholders that can be used in the body, and the program will replace these placeholders with prompts.

Comment: @TonWin TBH I would not use settings mechanism for that. Personally I would set up some convention (maybe using settings) so users can just drop files for bodies somewhere and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I've also defined Body as `Dictionary<string, string>`, where the value contains the original content that was under the `Body` node. However, this approach becomes very cumbersome when filling out the JSON configuration file. Is there a better way to do this?

Example of the "body" field in the JSON configuration file:

```json
"body": "{\"model\": \"gpt-3.5-turbo\", \"messages\": [{\"role\": \"user\", \"content\": \"hello!\"}], \"temperature\": 0.7}"
```

Answer (score 0):

naitive config deserialiazation works only for one level. If you have a nested objects , better to use this syntax

```
  var json = File.ReadAllText(configFilePath);

  var result = JObject.Parse(json)["apiClientOptions"]
                      .ToObject<HttpApiClientOptions>();
```

test

```
string role = (string) ((JArray) result.Body["messages"])[0]["role"]; // "user"
```